# How to determine if variable contains a specified string using RegEx

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

How can I write a condition which will compare Recipient.AdressEntry for example with the following String "I351" using RegEx?

Here is my If condition which works but is hardcoded to every known email address.

```
For Each recip In recips
    If recip.AddressEntry = "Dov John, I351" Then
        objMsg.To = "example@mail.domain"
        objMsg.CC = recip.Address
        objMsg.Subject = Msg.Subject
        objMsg.Body = Msg.Body
        objMsg.Send
    End If
Next
```

The reason I need this condition is email may have one of several colleagues from my team and one or more from another team. AdressEntry of my colleagues ends with I351 so I will check if this email contains one of my teammates.

```
For Each recip In recips
    If (recip.AddressEntry = "Dov John, I351" _
          Or recip.AddressEntry = "Vod Nohj, I351") Then
        objMsg.To = "example@mail.domain"
        objMsg.CC = recip.Address
        objMsg.Subject = Msg.Subject
        objMsg.Body = Msg.Body
        objMsg.Send
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What are the rules for the inputs? And what _exactly_ is the condition? A string that ends with `I351`? If so, you don't even need regex, you can simply use `If recip.AddressEntry Like "*I351"`, if not, please explain the rules for the input string (aka `recip.AddressEntry`).

Comment: Its an Object Outlook.MeetingItem.Recipient.AdressEntry. I will try your proposal `"*I351"`

Comment: This is not what I meant. I mean what is the format of the input string and what is the condition you want to use? For example, do you only want to check if the string ends with "I351"? Do you want to check if it matches two words followed by a comma and then "I351? Or what exactly do you want to check for?

Comment: Ill updaet my question

Comment: recip.AddressEntry returns an AddressEntry object, not a string. Did you mean recip.AddressEntry.Name?

Comment: I don't know how it works although its an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still didn't clarify *exactly* what the condition you want to use for matching is, so I'll do my best:

- If you simply want to check if the string ends with "I351", you don't need regex, you can use something like the following:

  ```
  If recip.AddressEntry Like "*I351" Then
      ' ...
  End If
  ```
- If you want to check if the string follows this format `"LastName FirstName, I351"`, you can achieve that using Regex by using something like the following:

  ```
  Dim regEx As New RegExp
  regEx.Pattern = "^\w+\s\w+,\sI351$"
  If regEx.Test(recip.AddressEntry) Then
      ' ...
  End If
  ```

  **Explanation of the regex pattern:**

  ```
  ' ^      Asserts position at the start of the string.
  ' \w     Matches any word character.
  ' +      Matches between one and unlimited times.
  ' \s     Matches a whitespace character.
  ' \w+    Same as above.
  ' ,      Matches the character `,` literally.
  ' \s     Matches a whitespace character.
  ' I351   Matches the string `I351` literally.
  ' $      Asserts position at the end of the string.
  ```

  [Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/dD2HKc/1).

Hope that helps.

Comment: what is "Test" its sometilg like check if equal?

Comment: Exactly, it checks if there's a match in the string that follows the pattern.

Comment: RegExp Works very well Thank You!!